# Como aumentar o tamanho de upload no php?

Tags: php, microsoft-excel, csv

Bom dia, preciso fazer um upload de um arquivo csv que é maior que o padrão php que é 2M (o arquivo tem em torno de 10 a 15M)
A aplicação funciona perfeitamente para arquivos menores que 2MB.

Já tentei de todas as formas aumentar esse limite e eu não consegui.
Alguém me ajuda?

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '15M');

ini_set('max_input_time', '200M');
ini_set('memory_limit', '250M');

set_time_limit(65536);
```

E depois eu dou um echo na variavel e nunca muda.

Comment: Você precisa configurar isso direto no arquivo `php.ini` do seu servidor. De acordo com a [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.list.php), a diretiva `upload_max_filesize` não pode ser alterada via `ini_set`.

Comment: Tem hospedagem que bloqueia o uso/criação, edição do php.ini, há serviços quem tem em seus painéis a opção de alterar o limite de upload por lá. Séria interessante contar eles para ver se o seu caso não é um destes.

Answer (score 1):

Localiza e altera no arquivo php.ini (no diretório raiz da sua hospedagem, geralmente public_html) esses dois parâmetros:

```
post_max_size = 25M
upload_max_filesize = 25M
```

Caso não tenha adicione as linhas.
Tem hospedagens em que é necessário colocar um `php.ini` no diretório em que será feito o upload com esses parametros.